# Does Policy Request needs Delay?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cross-domain-policy

My friend and i have been working on a multiplayer game in as3. Tests without policy request has successed on local, but at last we added it so we could test on the browser.

Weird stuff happened, because it managed to connect to the server, but it was needed to spam the connect button in order to start sending data.

With a timer the problem has been solved, but we dont want to wait 5 seconds in order to connect. I dont know what is wrong, and few information can be readed on the internet about this matter. Has someone experimented this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It probably is because the flash game has to be loaded in the cache first from web. it may be dependent on the internet speed, the computers cache, the browser you are using , etc. same goes to every other document, flash, HTML, etc. , testing it locally gives you instant access, but opening it from web would take time

Comment: The game does not connect to the server from the beggining. It needs a direction before trying to connect. So cache should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Policy request should not require you do add a delay manually, so there must be something else going on.

> Even though the method is named Security.loadPolicyFile(), a policy
>   file isn’t loaded until a network call that requires a policy file is
>   issued. Calls to loadPolicyFile() simply tell Flash Player where to
>   look for policy files when they are needed.
>
> You can’t receive notification of when a policy file request is
>   initiated or completed, and there is no reason to do so. Flash Player
>   performs policy checks asynchronously, and automatically waits to
>   initiate connections until after the policy file checks have
>   succeeded.

Source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e08.html

Comment: it sure manages to connect, but i cannot send anything immediately. First time we set the timer to wait 3 seconds, but then we increased the time again up to 6 seconds. I know that must sounds stupid.